# How to loop through a DB table and then search for duplicate records to delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a table storing some sound bites. I tried to create a loop which would read the table and then reread the table and delete and records which are close to being duplicates.

My code is something like this:

```
Numbersound.where{id != nil}.order(:id).each do |sound|
  Numbersound.where{(id != sound.id) & (sound.wavelength = wavelength)}.each do |duplicate|
    if (duplicate.wavecount != nil)
      #compare wave files and check if the same
      if MatchSound.compare(sound.frames, sound.wavecount, duplicate.frames, duplicate.wavecount, 0.03)
        Numbersound.delete(duplicate.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I need to remove the deleted record from the sound array as otherwise there will always be at least one match (itself).

I can't use SQL to do the comparison as I have some fairly long calculations to perform.

Comment: [You mean something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2790068/1013138) There's a comparison by name but you could just override it with your match method.

Comment: You seem to be missing an `end`.

Comment: Thanks for the link naliwajek.